# Is there a DLL or any other requirements for SignalR server to work?

Tags: c#, winforms, server, signalr

I've been looking and looking all over to what is the reason why my server doesn't start. I got the C# WinForms version from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b),  This is the snippet, working fine at my end, it starts the server using localhost and my local ip address.

```
try
{
      SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
}
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
      WriteToConsole("Server failed to start because " + ex.Message);
      //Re-enable button to let user try to start server again
      this.Invoke((Action)(() => ButtonStart.Enabled = true));
      return;
}
this.Invoke((Action)(() => ButtonStop.Enabled = true));
WriteToConsole("Server started at " + ServerURI);
```

but for some reason, on some laptops and computers, it doesn't work. It does not start the server and doesn't catch the error too. So I don't know what's causing the problem.

I built the release version, copied the release folder to another PC to test, and its working fine, you just have to *run as admin*

Then I copied to the pc who is supposed to use the server app, it doesn't start.

I already installed .Net 4.5.2 and 4.6 which is the *supposed to be requirement*, its still not working. I don't know what I am missing. Is there anything that I need to install?

Comment: A better way is to say here is the **ERROR** and slap it in our faces. Then tell us what you've done and what doesn't work. Actual vs expected results, with links to research. Starting off asking *what are all the requirements or is there a dll needed to get it to work* is not a good troubleshooting strategy. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @JeremyThompson I know how to ask a good question here. I just downloaded the solution, and it works fine. Then I tried to other PCs, the server doesn't start. I looked up for solutions/requirements then only found out that .Net 4.5 is all I needed. So I installed it, and its still doesn't start the server. I already googled, but nothing suggests an answer, so I posted here, maybe someone knows.

Comment: You really need to give "it doesn't work" and "the server doesn't start" an explanation. If you cannot, that clearly indicates your testing needs further improvements, like writing to a log file showing what happens, and so on. It is useless to post such a question in its current state, as nobody can know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem while making my server client interaction to start, spent almost 3 hours battling my way through the Dlls and configurations. It seems like SignalR requires a few Dlls that you would need to add externally.

```
SignalrR
SignalR.Hubs
SignalR.Hosting.Common
Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener
```

One good sample project that helped me solve a lot of problem was this https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

If you still face issues, comment with the error message you get and I might be able to help further.

Comment: that link is where I downloaded the application. Its working fine on two laptops that I worked on. When I gave the application to my friend, the server doesn't start. I changed nothing from that code. So I wonder how it works o n my pc and not his.

Comment: Check for references folders in each of the projects on your friends computer and see if there are any missing Dlls from yours or if the Dlls have a yellow warning on them.